# Is it possible to select blending type in OpenCV stitcher python

Tags: python, opencv, alphablending, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I'm using `open-cv==3.4.2` for stitching images in python.

```
import cv2
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher()
(status, stitched_panorama) = stitcher.stitch(image_array)
```

In the file [blenders](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/stitching/src/blenders.cpp#L68-L77) from opencv source code, I see there are implementations of both blending types `Feather` and `Multi Band`. But there is no option to select this from the [`stitch`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html#a37ee5bacf229e9d0fb9f97c8f5ed1acd) method. Is it possible to select the blending type while stitching the images? If yes, how? If not, can you please tell me which method is used by default?

Comment: I don't have an OpenCV 3.4.2 environment available, so commenting on the most recent version: There's some [`setBlender`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html#a79651cf9e4b87cb6af26caa0535b9baa) method, which might does what you want to achieve - BUT there seems to be NO Python binding at the moment. (PyCharm function listing for `cv2.Stitcher` doesn't show any methods in that direction.) So, I guess, there's also no Python binding for that functionaility in OpenCV 3.4.2.

Comment: See Stitcher_create([, mode]) at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/17/image-stitching-with-opencv-and-python/. But I think it is only available in OpenCV 4

Comment: @fmw42 [Mode](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html#a114713924ec05a0309f4df7e918c0324)'s something different here.

Comment: OK. Sorry, That was just a guess. Thanks HansHirse.